# How do I query a user value in one table to a column header and get value under header?

Tags: php, mysql

### Situation

I have two tables:

[image: tables]

- SGL= Single (one person in room)
- DBL = Double (two people in the room)
- TPL = Triple (three people).

and so on.  (CHD = child in room; discounted occupancy).

The *clients* table contains user inserted values.  The *tourprices* table is preset rates for roomtypes.

### Question

Is there a way to query such that the user inserted roomtype is compared to the column header of tourprices table such that the result is the price for the date under that column header?

For example:  the user wishes to book two people (DBL) onto the tour for 27-Feb-2012.  How do I write the query to pull the $200 rate based on the given?

```
SELECT c.roomtype, t.SGL, t.DBL, t.TPL, t.QUD, t.CHD
FROM clients c, tourprices t
WHERE c.roomtype = ??????
```

thanks!

Comment: Doing this operations in programs rather in databases is much more convenient. Your considerations?

Comment: You could avoid this problem if you moved the type-dependent info into a separate table, with a different row for each date+roomtype. Then you can do a normal join on the Roomtype columns.

Comment: @barmar - actually, I had that setup but the de-normalized spread caused multiple results to the query even if SELECT DISTINCT is used.

Comment: If you got multiple results then either your database structure was wrong or you didn't have all the necessary join conditions in your WHERE clause.

Comment: exaclty.  Had, for example, SGL repeated multiple times across the table.  Here, it's only indicated once.  Price might repeat (though not likely) but there's a tour code to set it apart.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `CASE` Statement to look at what value `Roomtype` is and grab the appropriate column from `Tourprices` that has that type to determine the price.

```
SELECT c.Roomtype
   , CASE
        WHEN c.Roomtype = 'SGL' THEN tp.SGL
        WHEN c.Roomtype = 'DBL' THEN tp.DBL
        WHEN c.Roomtype = 'TPL' THEN tp.TPL
        WHEN c.Roomtype = 'QUD' THEN tp.QUD
        WHEN c.Roomtype = 'CHD' THEN tp.CHD
     END AS RateOfTour
FROM Clients AS c
INNER JOIN Tourprices AS tp ON c.tourstart = tp.tourstartp
```

Comment: This answer should work, however you really ought think about normalizing your database.

Comment: @Mike, not sure how I could possibly normalize this price table further other than to make a separate table for each room type BUT given that there are 26 tours, with 20+ dates per tour x 5 roomtypes each ... that's 2600 tables.

Comment: @mike I'm trying to revise my database as you suggest.  Question:  What would be under the headers in your suggested 'room_types' table with column headers "SGL, SGL_w_child, DBL, DBL_w_child,..." and so on?  (Trying to understand the use of the table).  ...sorry, as you likely deduced, I am a complete beginner at this but am learning and understanding.

Comment: @shane The RoomTypes could have 2 columns RoomTypeId and Description.  You would then be able to have 1 = 'Single', 2 = 'Single With Child', 3 = 'Double', etc...

Comment: @Adam thanks. Do you mind if I collaborate with you further on this? I want to get this project working so I can stop using MS Excel as a database.

Comment: @shane I'm not sure what you're looking for in terms of collaboration.  I'm on SO frequently and try to answer questions here.  If you have something specific that you do not understand, or query troubles, posting it here or dba.stackechange.com (more for design) you should be able to provide help when you're stuck.  If you're having trouble on generic relational DB concepts, I would recommend reading up on them a bit before trying to tackle a design.  There are a lot of good resources available online.

Comment: @Adam that's pretty much what I was hoping for ... able to ask a question or two more when I'm stuck.  I read up on the normal forms of DB design and have been reading and learning PHP, HTML, + MySql for about two years on my own.  This is my first attemtp at a database with more than one table in MySQL.  I designed a pricing database in excel that does much of what I'm trying to achieve here but it has no means of posting client info and, of course, online interface.  Hence my self-taught learning process.